# Running task periodically in Docker container without cancellation issues on endless loop

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, cron

I'm Dockerizing [ssh-key-authority](https://github.com/operasoftware/ssh-key-authority) and made an Apache2 container that serves the PHP application. To sync users, the script `scripts/ldap_update.php` should run periodically every xx min. So I created a second container in my `docker-compose.yml` file that reuses the Apache image containing phps binary:

```
version: '2' 
services: 
  ska: 
    image: ska
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        # Allow fetching packages from the internet in corporate environments
        http_proxy: ${http_proxy}
    env_file: docker.env
    ports:
      - 80:80

  ska-db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    env_file: docker.env

  cron: 
    image: ska
    volumes_from:
      - ska
    env_file: docker.env
    depends_on:
      - ska-db
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c '
        ./prepare-docker-configs.sh
        # Wait for DB connection
        sleep 10

        while true
        do 
          echo Running update task
          php /ska/scripts/ldap_update.php
          sleep 10
        done'
```

10s are for testing only. Productive I'd increase this to lets say 1800 (30 min). While this works, it has a problem: Docker couldn't stop this `while true` loop, e.g. when executing `docker-compose down`. As result, [Docker waits 10s and then kill the container process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596732/3276634).

This causes delays during development and it seems not to be a clean way for handling this. I found [trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html), which worked well outside Docker using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'kill -TERM -s SIGKILL $PID' SIGINT SIGTERM
PID=$$
echo pid: $PID

while true
do
    echo sleep run
    sleep 10
done
```

Result:

```
$ ./trap.sh 
pid: 26135
sleep run
^CKilled
```

But when trying this in the `ENTRYPOINT` (even with `exec`), the container just exited:

```
entrypoint: |
  bash -c '
    ./prepare-docker-configs.sh

    set -x
    PID=$$
    exec "trap 'kill -TERM -s SIGKILL $PID' SIGINT SIGTERM"
    echo "pid is $$"
    
    while true
    do
      sleep 10
      echo sync ldap users 
      php /ska/scripts/ldap_update.php
    done'
```

The only alternative I see is installing `cron` and [running it in the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37458519/9428314), but that seems a bit overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kill container process and not wait for 10 seconds, try:

```
docker-compose kill -s SIGINT
```

SIGTERM only reaches `bash` whereas SIGINT reaches `sleep`